# How to get the SQL error origin of an UnexpectedRollbackException

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, exception, transactions

I have a rollback exception with hibernate on my service "duplicateContract"

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1031)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:321)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy128.duplicateContracts(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.server.rpc.SrvContractImpl.duplicateContracts(SrvContractImpl.java:699)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at org.objectweb.jotm.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:329)
    at org.objectweb.jotm.Current.commit(Current.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1028)
    ... 47 more
```

The problem is, I just can't debug that, there is an error with the persisted object somewhere but I have no clue ( it's not a timeout or missing @Transactional ). How can I get more details for this exception ?  ( maybe somewhere in oracle log ? but where ? ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the JOTM source code and, to my surprise, [they don't propagate the original exception](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ow2.jotm/jotm-core/2.1.9/org/objectweb/jotm/TransactionImpl.java).

```
try {
    propagateCtx = false;
    term.commit(true);
    propagateCtx = true;
} catch (TransactionRolledbackException e) {
    Current.getCurrent().forgetTx(getXid());
    if (TraceTm.jta.isDebugEnabled()) {
        TraceTm.jta.debug("Commit distributed transaction -> rolled back!");
    }
    localstatus = Status.STATUS_ROLLEDBACK;
    throw new RollbackException();
} 
...
```

The JOTM project development [seems to have stopped](http://jotm.ow2.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/Download_Releases) (last two releases adate back to 2006 and 2010), so you should better check [Narayana](http://narayana.io/), [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/Main/WebHome) or [Bitronix](https://github.com/bitronix/btm).